# What are the best practices for preparing an iOS demo app along with main app?

Tags: ios, xcode

This question is about the App development/testing process. I've an app on the App Store (say `ABC`); now I added some features on a separate git code branch and want to show these to my teammates.

I can use TestFlight to install it on their iPhones, although that overwrites my original app on the phone.

I'm looking for the best way to get a new App, say `ABC Demo`, installed on their iPhones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the "new" version of the app to work alongside the old version on the same device then each app will have to have different Bundle Ids. You can achieve this by creating a new Target in Xcode

http://www.itexico.com/blog/bid/99497/iOS-Mobile-Development-Using-Xcode-Targets-to-Reuse-the-Code

[image]

two finger click the existing target and select `Duplicate`

Then under the new target change the Bundle Identifier to something different

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to `Targets` in `Xcode`
2. `Get Info` on your project's target
3. Search for `Product Name` under    `Packaging`. Change it to `ABC Demo`
4. Press Enter